# Discrete Binary Search in Topcoder Tutorial

Tags: binary-search

I went through this code given in [Topcoder binary search tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch).

```
binary_search(lo, hi, p):
    while lo < hi:
        mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2
        if p(mid) == true:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid+1

    if p(lo) == false:
        complain                // p(x) is false for all x in S!

    return lo                   // lo is the least x for which p(x) is true
```

I am not able to reason as to why always low is going to point to what we want i.e. lo is the least x for which p(x) is true ?

I have tried this on examples and this comes out to be true but I am not able to think about it logically.

Some sort of proof using some invariant which is maintained in the loop will be helpful .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is more of a logical one:

If the while loop has to terminate then `lo` should become equal to or greater than `hi`. Assuming we work with integers, then `lo` will be equal to `hi` and `hi` will be `mid`.

Answer (score 0):

In your language, the loop invariant is, lo is the least x in the search space that p(x) *can be* true. The loop makes progress by cutting the search space in half while maintaining the invariant. When the loop exits, search space has only one value, lo (which equals hi). We perform the last check, if p(lo) equals false, then we didn't find any x that makes p(x) true. Otherwise, it's the least x we look for.